# How to Enable a Button's Property Pages in Visual Studio 2013 with CDialog Class

Tags: button, visual-studio-2013, properties, cdialog

In Visual Studio 2008, it is possible to double click on a button from the resource view of a CDialog box and be directed right to the code that will help me edit its actions. However, in 2013, when I double click on a button, an "Add Class Wizard" window pops up. I just want to edit what my button does. How can I do this? In the button's properties window, the "property pages" button (the wrench) is disabled, and when I click on the "control events" button (the lightning bolt), there is nothing to select.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking strictly for properties, right click the mouse and select "**Properties**".  Additionally, you can right click the mouse on the button and select "**Add Event Handler...**" from the popup menu.  That should display an *Event Handler Wizard* dialog that will allow you pick any number of events that the control supports.  Note, however, if your resources are stored in a resource only dll, this approach can be problematic.